# How to get element to transform progressively based on scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, jquery-waypoints

I am attempting to use waypoints for two specific functions.

1. To identify if a user is scrolling up or down and the container comes into view. This is not working.
2. The second thing I am trying to figure out how to do doesn't necessarily have to do with waypoints. I want the image you see in the snippet to progressively `transform: translateX` based on the scroll progression. I am not sure how to do this. I put translate in the snippet to show the movement.

[If you go to this site](https://fishermenlabs.com/) and scroll down a little to the "Nike and Snapchat" section, you will see a phone image of Lebron. As you progressively scroll up or down, the image moves accordingly. This is what I am trying to replicate.

Does anyone know what I can do to achieve this?

```js
var homeMainSec =  $('#homeMainSec');
 
homeMainSec.waypoint(function(direction) {
  if (direction === 'down') {
    $('#homeBoxGridRight img').addClass('slideLeftDisplay');
    console.log('Left Slide');
  }
}, {
  offset: '25%'
});
homeMainSec.waypoint(function(direction) {
  if (direction === 'up') {
    $('#homeBoxGridRight img').addClass('slideRightDisplay');
    console.log('Right Slide');
  }
}, {
  offset: '25%'
});
```

```css
#homeMainSec {
 width: 100%;
 height: 95vh;
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 70px;
}
.homeMainBlock {
 height: 100%;
 width: 50%;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
/*- HomeBoxGridRight Section -*/
#homeBoxGridRight img {
 display: block;
 width: 40%;
 height: auto;
 margin-left: 50%;
}
.slideLeftDisplay {
 transform: translateX(-100px);-webkit-transform: translateX(-100px);
 transition: 1s;-webkit-transition: 1s;
 opacity: 1;
}
.slideRightDisplay {
 transform: translateX(100px);-webkit-transform: translateX(100px);
 transition: 1s;-webkit-transition: 1s;
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<section id="homeMainSec">
  <div class="homeMainBlock" id="homeBoxGridLeft">
  </div><div class="homeMainBlock" id="homeBoxGridRight">
    <img src="https://slidesjs.com/examples/standard/img/example-slide-1.jpg" alt="Image">
  </div>
</section>
<br><br><Br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

This gives you page scroll position for vertical scroll

```
window.pageYOffset
```

This gives you total scroll height for body

```
document.querySelector("body").scrollHeight
```

You need to subtract the height of scrollbar element that is given by

```
document.scrollingElement.offsetHeight
```

You can translate with respect to ratio of vertical scroll position and body height

```
window.pageYOffset/(document.querySelector("body").scrollHeight - document.scrollingElement.offsetHeight)
```

This will give you, ratio of current position to max scrollable position.
Manipulate it as you like to translate the elements wrt their initial position.

[image: Here's a sscreenshot with different scroll positions]